# How to change cursor when mouse pointer is over a bold word in RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, cursor, richtextbox

I want to change cursor to the HAND when mouse pointer is over a **bold** word in RichTextBox. How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this function to richtextbox.OnMouseMove event.

```
private void richTextBox2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int c = richTextBox2.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            richTextBox2.Select(c, 1);
            if (richTextBox2.SelectionFont.Bold)
            {
                richTextBox2.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
            }
            else
            {
                richTextBox2.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            }

        }
```

You just need 1 char to know if it is bold.

Answer (score 1):

- Register an OnMouseMove handler
- Call [GetCharIndexFormPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.getcharindexfromposition.aspx)
- Determine if that index is over a bolded character
- Set the [Cursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.cursor.aspx) property as desired.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but my problem is Step 3 (•Determine if that index is over a bolded character), How to determine without changing SelectionStart and SelectionLength?