# Determine which word mouse is hovering over in a FastColoredTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making use of the [`FastColoredTextBox`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting) project and cannot figure out how to determine what word (or character position) the mouse is hovering over when a MouseHover event is fired (So I can display a hint about the word's usage). I have found a similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476325/how-to-change-cursor-when-mouse-pointer-is-over-a-bold-word-in-richtextbox), though it only deals with a `RichTextBox` which conveniently has the [`GetCharIndexFromPosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.getcharindexfromposition.aspx) method.

*This might be a long shot but has anyone here worked with a `FastColoredTextBox` in this manner and could help?*

Otherwise, snooping around in the source for the `FastColoredTextBox` I cannot actually tell the control it uses to draw the text. Though I suspect from its class declaration

```
public partial class FastColoredTextBox : UserControl, ISupportInitialize
```

That it might do it itself. I think my best bet would be to look at how `RickTextBox` implements `GetCharIndexFromPosition` and try to recreate it with `FastColoredTextBox`.

*Any suggestions on how to approach this?*

**EDIT:** In the source for FCTB I started at the `MouseClick` event because this event moves the cursor when a user clicks the text so it must at some point from the character under the mouse. Within the event handler I located the method `public Place PointToPlace(Point point)`. It looks like this might be what I am looking for.

I will post an answer to the question if this leads me to a solution.

Comment: The source draws the text out at their positions, so as it draws each character save its location in a `Dictionary<Point, char>`. You can then match characters up to words, i.e. when there is a whitespace character it is the end of the word. Then from this you can find the words at specified points. Not the nicest but should be quite trivial to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PointToPlace` returns a `Place` which tells you the line and character index (on the line).
`PointToPosition` returns the absolute character position.
I tested this <sup>(in vb.net...)</sup>, it is not optimized but a first start and works so far:

```
Private Sub test_MouseMove(snd As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    Dim p As Integer = Me.fctb.PointToPosition(Me.fctb.PointToClient(Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position))
    ' display letter
    Dim ch As String = ""
    If p < Me.fctb.Text.Length Then ch = Me.fctb.Text.ToCharArray()(p)
    Me.Label1.Text = ch
    ' display word
    Me.Label2.Text = GetWord(Me.fctb, p)
End Sub

Private Function GetWord(ct As FastColoredTextBoxNS.FastColoredTextBox, p As Integer) As String
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder(ct.Text)
    If sb.Length = 0 OrElse p = sb.Length Then Return ""
    If Not Regex.IsMatch(sb.Chars(p).ToString, "^\w$") Then Return sb.Chars(p).ToString
    Dim n1 As Integer = p
    While n1 > 0 AndAlso Regex.IsMatch(sb.Chars(n1 - 1).ToString, "^\w$")
        n1 -= 1
    End While
    Dim n2 As Integer = p
    While n2 < sb.Length AndAlso Regex.IsMatch(sb.Chars(n2 + 1).ToString, "^\w$")
        n2 += 1
    End While

    Return sb.ToString.Substring(n1, n2 - n1 + 1)
End Function
```

---

C# code:

```
private void test_MouseMove(object snd, MouseEventArgs e) {
    var p = fctb.PointToPosition(fctb.PointToClient(Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position));
    // display letter
    var ch = "";
    if (p < fctb.Text.Length) {
        ch = fctb.Text[p].ToString();
    }
    Label1.Text = ch;
    // display word
    Label2.Text = GetWord(fctb, p);
}

private string GetWord(FastColoredTextBoxNS.FastColoredTextBox ct, int p) {
    var sb = new StringBuilder(ct.Text);
    if (sb.Length == 0 || p == sb.Length) return "";
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(sb[p].ToString(), @"^\w$")) return sb[p].ToString();
    var n1 = p;
    while (n1 > 0 && Regex.IsMatch(sb[n1 - 1].ToString(), @"^\w$")) {
        n1 -= 1;
    }
    var n2 = p;
    while (n2 < sb.Length && Regex.IsMatch(sb[n2 + 1].ToString(), @"^\w$")) {
        n2 += 1;
    }

    return sb.ToString().Substring(n1, n2 - n1 + 1);
}
```

Comment: I think this will get me started! I will post a C# solution once I have created it but mark yours as the solution for your work. // What does the regex `^\w$` match?

Comment: @KDecker: I took the liberty of converting the code to C# (may still have minor mistakes, but hopefully not). The regex `^\w$` matches a single "word" (letters, numbers and underscore, usually) character. I'd probably use one of the `char.Is*` methods, e.g. `char.IsLetterOrDigit`. This also removes the need of converting characters to one-character strings in a loop here, which is a bit questionable.

Comment: Yes, thanks, there is probably room for improvement. `^\w$` is used on single chars, so the anchors are not needed either. `\w` matches letters, numbers, underscore as Joey said, but excluding non-English letters `\p{L}` matches any (unicode) letter, might be better.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've decided that the `MouseHover` event is not how I wish to display information about a word. It does not fire when I would like, I think I am going to use keyboard shortcuts to display the information I would like.

Though before I quit I did come up with this partial solution in C#. It has a few bugs. When hovering over the very last word of the text there is sometimes and issue. Also I feel like my mixing of `char` and `String` causes some esoteric issues that I didn't track down.

```
private void fctbEditor_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int charIndex = fctbEditor.PointToPosition(fctbEditor.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
    if (charIndex != fctbEditor.Text.Length && fctbEditor.Text.Length > 0 && fctbEditor.Text[charIndex] != ' ')
    {
        String hoverWord = GetWord(charIndex);

        // Do with the word as you please
        Console.Out.WriteLine(" - Index: " + charIndex + " Char[" + fctbEditor.Text[charIndex].ToString() + "] Word[" + hoverWord + "]");
    }
}

private String GetWord(int charPos)
{
    int revPos = charPos;
    char curChar = fctbEditor.Text[revPos];
    while (curChar != ' ' && curChar != '\n' && revPos > 0)
    {
        revPos -= 1;
        curChar = fctbEditor.Text[revPos];
    }

    int forPos = charPos;
    curChar = fctbEditor.Text[forPos];
    while(curChar != ' ' && curChar != '\n' && forPos < fctbEditor.Text.Length)
    {
        forPos += 1;
        curChar = fctbEditor.Text[forPos];
    }

    return fctbEditor.Text.Substring(revPos + 1, forPos - revPos - 1);
}
```